# Cycle detection in non-iterated sequence

Tags: algorithm, cycle-detection

My understanding is that [tortoise-hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) like algorithms works on iterated sequences
That is, for any x, succ(x) = x0.

I would like to implement an algortihm that can detect cycles in both deterministic and non-deterministic infinite repeating sequences.

The sequences may have a non-repeating prefix subsequence, for example in the sequence `1666666...`, has the prefix of `1` and the repeating pattern `6`.

This algorithm would return the longest repeating pattern in a sequence.
The repeating pattern of `001100110011...` would be `0011`, the repeating pattern of `22583575837583758...` would be `58357`.

My idea was to generate a guess of the longest possible pattern length somehow go from there, but I can't get things in order.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? you're not very clear

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough, I edited the question

Comment: Are you looking for the most repeated consecutive substring or the longest? Or a mix of both? Also, should the sequence always start at zero or can it be in between?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut The sequences  have a non-repeating prefix (possibly empty sequence) followed by a repeating sequence. The sequence always starts at 0. I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tortoise-hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) algorithm uses same address to identify cycles.  This problem requires a different sort of algorithm.  Some form of trie or structure such as LZW compression, would be where I would look for a solution.